# How would I convert this array to usable javascript array?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, highcharts

I have php code that returns this from a database,

```
[
{
    "Time": "2012-11-27 16:10:35",
    "NumPlayers": "1"
},
{
    "Time": "2012-11-27 16:24:55",
    "NumPlayers": "1"
},
{
    "Time": "2012-11-27 16:25:37",
    "NumPlayers": "2"
},
{
    "Time": "2012-11-27 16:29:33",
    "NumPlayers": "2"
```

The times are MySQL timestamps. I need to get it into this format to use with Highcharts javascript charting.

```
data: [
[Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
[Date.UTC(1970,  9, 14), 0.15],
[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 28), 0.35],
[Date.UTC(1970, 11, 12), 0.46],
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through the MySQL results and convert the timestamps to javascript Date.UTC objects. I need to place the NumPlayers value after the Date.UTC objects, and output it in the format below. I'm a PHP and javascript noob :\

It should look something like this:

```
data: [
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 10, 35), 1],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 24, 55), 1],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 25, 37), 2],
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 29, 33), 2],
```

Comment: maybe moment.js is a solution http://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: you can parse your data and after build an simple array.. I cannot understand what you really want..

Comment: @GerardWesterhof It's usually better to do parsing on the server if you can get away with it, and in this case, the OP can.

Comment: Probably the best solution is parse on the backend, like @JuanMendes mentioned.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann But don't do the parsing on your own as some have suggested

Comment: @JuanMendes No because I was working. Take a look my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that `Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 10, 35)` simply returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch (`1356624635000`). Therefore, you can just convert your object into UNIX timestamps (times a 1000 since JS works with millisecond timestamps, but PHP works with seconds).

**[Sample Code](http://codepad.org/sEsnmG18)**

```
$data = '[{"Time": "2012-11-27 16:10:35", "NumPlayers": "1"}, {"Time": "2012-11-27 16:24:55", "NumPlayers": "1"}]';

// Make sure date is parsed as UTC
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

// Convert items into the desired format
$mapper = function($item) {
    return array(strtotime($item->Time)*1000, $item->NumPlayers);
}

echo json_encode(array_map($mapper, json_decode($data)));
```

**Output**

```
[[1354032635000,"1"],[1354033495000,"1"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting straight JSON from your database, which you can always convert into an array:

```
$data = '[{"Time": "2012-11-27 16:10:35", "NumPlayers": "1"}, {"Time": "2012-11-27 16:24:55", "NumPlayers": "1"}]';
$arrayData = json_decode($data, true);
```

After which you can simply iterate through the array and print out the contents of the array in the JS format you need. Something like that:

```
echo 'data: [' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($arrayData as $item) {
    echo '[Date.UTC(';
    $tmp = preg_split( '/(-| |\:)/', $item['Time'] );
    echo implode(', ', $tmp);
    echo '), ' . $item['NumPlayers'] . '],';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL . '];';
```

Comment: The question is specifically about making them dates, `json_decode` isn't going to do that. You have to do it on the client since JSON doesn't support dates

Comment: @JuanMendes the output is the same as the OP wanted it http://codepad.org/DTlp0pr2

Comment: Now that you added extra code to generate the JSON (which is not valid JSON) on your own, yes it will

Comment: The second chunk of code, which takes the result of `json_decode` and makes an almost JSON string out of it, that was added after my initial comments

Comment: I just submitted an answer that doesn't involve generating pseudo-JSON on your own. It sends properly formatted JSON over the wire (that is because `Date.UTC` just returns a number)

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the time string into sections using `/[^\d]+/g`:

```
var finalData = [], numbers=/[^\d]+/g, item, dateParts, newDate;
for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
     item = data[i];
     dateParts = item.Time.split(numbers);
     newDate = Date.UTC.apply(Date, dateParts);
     finalData.push([newDate, item.NumPlayers]);
}
```

See also: [MDN's documentation on JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (`/[^\d]/g` is a regex).

Comment: I prefer this approach of doing it on the client, so that proper JSON is sent over the wire, not JS as `[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 27, 16, 10, 35), 1],`. My only recommendation would be to have the server send a timestamp so the client doesn't need to parse the time

Comment: Except that you're splitting on the wrong thing, you need to split on the separators, not on the numbers. Also, your call to `Date.apply` is incorrect, it should be calling the UTC method. Notice your code is giving the wrong timestamps.http://jsfiddle.net/ck9bL/ But this one http://jsfiddle.net/ck9bL/3/works well. You should update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I provided a server side answer that doesn't require parsing on the server side and doesn't require generating JSON on your won.

Comment: @JuanMendes - *Chuckles*, yep, that's the exact opposite of what I wanted - I've updated my answer.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You should try your code... It still doesn't work, look at http://jsfiddle.net/ck9bL/3/ for working code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to provide data to Highcharts is getting data formated from database, so that you don't have to do it on client side.

To do it you just have to change your `query` to something like the following.

**Backend**
`$query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) * 1000 AS 'date', value FROM ...";`

Then to send the result to frontend:
`echo json_encode($result);`

**Frontend**
To get the result on frontend, this case using jQuery and assuming that `url` is your url:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    // decode json
    var data = $.parseJSON(json);
    // Then you just have to pass it to your series
});
```

Or better, store date values in UTC.

Comment: If the OP can do this, even better, no need to parse time strings

Answer (score 0):

```
    var php_data = [
        {
            "Time": "2012-11-27 16:10:35",
            "NumPlayers": "1"
        },
        {
            "Time": "2012-11-27 16:24:55",
            "NumPlayers": "1"
        }
    ];

    var length = php_data.length;
    hc_data = [];

    for(var i = 0; i< length; i++){
      php_date = new Date(php_data[i]["Time"]);
      hc_data.push(
        [
            Date.UTC(
                php_date.getFullYear(), 
                php_date.getMonth() + 1, 
                php_date.getDate()
            ),
            php_data[i]["NumPlayers"]
        ]
      );
    }

    // hc_data is your Array
```